# How to keep localization files synchronized in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint, localization, spfx

I am writing an SPFx web part in Visual Studio Code. When you localize an SPFx extension, you have to deal with at least two files (usually more), like this
(see more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts):

`en-us.js`:

```js
define([], function() {
  return {
    Advanced: "Advanced",
    ShowValidations: "Show Validations",
    ShowProgress: "Show Progress",
    ....
```

`strings.d.ts`

```js
declare interface IVistoWebPartStrings {
  Advanced: string;
  ShowValidations: string;
  ShowProgress: string;
  ......
```

Now every time you add a new string, you need to add to all files. This is really annoying.
How can I avoid this? So that when I add a string, it is automatically added everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great open source VS Code extension to do the job, if anyone interested. It keeps all strings in a CSV file and auto-generates .ts and .js files

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.vscode-spfx-localization